# Unable to create webgl context in Chromium when webvr is enabled?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, chromium, webvr

I am using Chromium version 54.0.2790.0 which is the latest version.

The problem is, when webvr is enabled (chrome://flags -> webvr -> Enable) both of the following functions return `null`.

```
canvas.getContext('webgl');
canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
```

But if i disable webvr support, those functions work and return `WebGLRenderingContext` as expected.

What could be the reason behind this?

Thanks

**Update:**

I am using the built in Intel HD4600 Graphics card and the driver is updated.

I tried to check the GPU features using chrome://gpu in Chromium. My main target was to see if it uses different GPU driver in case i enable webvr. I found out that -

If webvr is disabled, chrome://gpu gives me this -

```
Pixel shader version    5.0
Vertex shader version   5.0 
GL_VENDOR               Google Inc.
GL_RENDERER             ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)
GL_VERSION              OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.1220bbbd564a)
```

If webvr is enabled, chrome://gpu gives me this -

```
Pixel shader version    4.00
Vertex shader version   4.00    
GL_VENDOR               Intel
GL_RENDERER             Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
GL_VERSION              4.0.0 - Build 9.18.10.3071
```

Also, i have tested it using NVIDIA's GTX 650Ti. The problem doesnt happen for that graphics card.

Could it be that the intel's graphics card is blacklisted?

Comment: Where did you get the chromium build from, is it the one with WebVR enabled from webvr.info? What is your OS?

Comment: I got the chromium build from this link - https://webvr.info/get-chrome/

And i am testing on Windows 7.

Comment: With a slightly older version and windows 10 these return a normal webgl context, will check with updated chromium with webvr...

Comment: The same with 54.0.2792.0 (64-bit) - does normal chrome WebGL work for you?

Comment: Yes, normal chrome webgl works perfectly. Even chromium works perfectly if i disable the webvr extension. Also, i have some interesting findings. Please check the update.